# How to separate methods from MyLayout.vue to a mixin.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I want to separate the methods of MyLayout.vue in a mixin.js

This is the original MyLayout.vue

```
<template>
...

    <q-layout-drawer
      v-model="leftDrawerOpen"
      :content-class="$q.theme === 'mat' ? 'bg-grey-2' : null"
    >
      <q-list no-border link inset-delimiter>
        <q-list-header>Listas de tareas</q-list-header>
        <q-item v-for="list of lists" :key="list._id" 
          :class="{active:list._id == selected}" @click.native="selected = list._id">
          <q-item-main :label="list.title" />
          <q-item-side right icon="delete" 
          v-if="selected == list._id"
          @click.native="deleteList(selected)"/>
        </q-item>
        <q-item>
          <q-item-main>
            <q-input v-model.trim="list.title" placeholder="+ Nueva lista" @keyup.enter="sendList"/>
          </q-item-main>
          <q-item-side right icon="format_color_fill">
            <q-popover>
              <q-color-picker v-model="list.color"/>
            </q-popover>
          </q-item-side>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-layout-drawer>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { openURL } from 'quasar'

class List {
  constructor(title = '', color = '') {
    this.title = title;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'MyLayout',
  data () {
    return {
      leftDrawerOpen: this.$q.platform.is.desktop,
      list: new List(),
      lists: [],
      selected: undefined,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getLists();
  },
    methods: {
        openURL,
        submit () {
          return
        },
        sendList() {
        if(this.list.title == '') { return }
        else {
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.list),
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              this.getLists();
              this.list = new List();
            });
        }
        },

      getLists() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.lists = data;
          });
      },

      deleteTask(listId) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists/' + listId, {
          method: 'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.getLists();
          });
      },
    }
}
</script>
```

And  I tried this:
mixins.js

```
export default {
  created: function() {
    this.getLists();
  },
  methods: {
    sendList: function() {
      if(this.list.title == '') { return }
      else {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.list),
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.getLists();
            this.list = new List();
          });
      }
    },

    getLists: function() {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.lists = data;
        });
    },

    deleteList: function(listId) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/lists/' + listId, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.getLists();
        });
    },
  }
}
```

(of course I delete the functions from MyLayout.vue)

I have this error (twice, like if the mixins runs two times don’t know why)

> Property or method “lists” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

It seems that if I put the methods in an external file it can not receive the data. I have also tried adding the following data to mixins.js before the methods:

```
data () {
    return {
      list: new List(),
      lists: [],
      selected: undefined,
    }
  },
```

but I get many more mistakes still

in MyLayout.vue

> Error in data(): “ReferenceError: List is not defined”
>
> Property or method “leftDrawerOpen” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
>
> Property or method “lists” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
>
> Error in render: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘title’ of undefined”
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘title’ of undefined

in mixins.js

> List is not defined

**Edit**: I tried with the class in the mixin.js too (out of the export default)... I still have the double error:

> "Property or method “lists” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render".

Comment: your `List` class would have to be in the mixin as well. I would probably put it in a separate file and import it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried too. I do not know where to put it and I have not seen any examples on the internet.

Comment: replace `created` with `beforeMount` lifecyclehook. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: Still have the "Property or method “lists” is not defined" error... you say that replace in the mixins.js, don't you?